# What will infinitesimals of derivative do with the mean value theorem?

Tags: calculus, infinitesimals, mean-value-theorem

[image]
I think these three proofs of increasing/decreasing are already very convincing. What I don't understand is the last sentence of the text

> "It's not a sure thing that these infinitesimals have anything to do
> with the non-infinitesimals behaviour of the function"

What will the infinitesimals do with the proof?

I've found the introduction of Infinitesimals on Wikipedia, but it tells nothing related to the mean value theorem. I'm a beginner in calculus and have little knowledge about infinitesimals. Can anyone tell me more about it?

Comment: The lack of quantifyers makes the text you quote quite bad… Besides, at undergraduate level, infinitesimal do not have a formal definition.

Comment: What do you mean by "lack of quantifiers"? What I don't understand in this question is the last sentence of the text "It's not a sure thing that these infinitesimals have anything to do with the non-infinitesimals behaviour of the function". How could the infinitesimals influence the proof?

Comment: @HaoyueYang . You find the formal proofs convincing and so do I . Lack of quantifiers means that those proofs could be improved (pun intended) by writing $\forall a,b,a<b$ and $\exists c$ etc. Honestly I cannot help thinking that the author of this book should have just written QED and not mention confusing stuff about infinitesimals.

Comment: "How could the infinitesimals influence the proof?" they cannot. At undergraduate level, you would not commit any mistake thinking that infinitesimals do not exist and have nothing to do with the subject (it is possible to build a theory of infinitesimals but it's precisely not the point here). The text you quote is bad because "increasing" doesn't mean "$a<b \Rightarrow f(a) < f(b)$", it means "$\forall a,b,\ a<b \Rightarrow f(a) < f(b)$". So, there are at least two reasons to abandon this book.

Comment: Thank you! Actually I'm self-studying MIT Calculus online courses, and sometimes I need to search online to solve any doubts, so this is why the article appears in my notebook...